# Converting results of a MySQL query into a string

Tags: php, mysql

My query is:

```
$orderitemsattributes_query = "SELECT products_options_values
FROM orders_products_attributes oa
WHERE oa.orders_id
IN (
SELECT DISTINCT o.orders_id
FROM orders o
WHERE o.exported =  '0'
AND o.orders_id >  '0')";
$orderitemsattributes_result = mysql_query($orderitemsattributes_query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($orderitemsattributes_result)) {

echo $row['products_options_values'];
}
```

gives me the following:

```
 6 period day (TP6)NavyGold (j)Gold Lamé (17)LJD1 at back (free)
```

I want to be able to convert this to a single string for insertion into another field on the database.

I tried:

```
$tradebox_attributes_list = implode (',', $row);`
```

but i either don't get anything, or i get incomplete results stored in $tradebox_attributes_list depending where i put the implode.

I need to be able to read this variable some way further along the code, well after the closing }.

Table Structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders_products_attributes` (
  `orders_products_attributes_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `orders_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `orders_products_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `products_options` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `products_options_values` text NOT NULL,
  `options_values_price` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `price_prefix` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `product_attribute_is_free` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `products_attributes_weight` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `products_attributes_weight_prefix` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `attributes_discounted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `attributes_price_base_included` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `attributes_price_onetime` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `attributes_price_factor` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `attributes_price_factor_offset` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `attributes_price_factor_onetime` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `attributes_price_factor_onetime_offset` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `attributes_qty_prices` text,
  `attributes_qty_prices_onetime` text,
  `attributes_price_words` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `attributes_price_words_free` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `attributes_price_letters` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `attributes_price_letters_free` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `products_options_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `products_options_values_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `products_prid` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `tradebox_attributes_list` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`orders_products_attributes_id`),
  KEY `idx_orders_id_prod_id_zen` (`orders_id`,`orders_products_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=77065 ;

Sample of one entry is:


(76569, 22959, 34813, 'Lesson format', '6 period day (TP6)', 0.0000, '+', 1, 0, '+', 1, 1, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, '', '', 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 5, 55, '30:499bc45895cd0baaef055a57cb36df5d', ''),
(76570, 22959, 34813, 'Cover', 'Navy', 0.0000, '+', 1, 0, '+', 1, 1, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, '', '', 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 1, 2, '30:499bc45895cd0baaef055a57cb36df5d', '1 at back (free)'),
(76571, 22959, 34813, 'Wire', 'Gold (j)', 0.0000, '', 1, 0, '', 1, 1, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, '', '', 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 4, 49, '30:499bc45895cd0baaef055a57cb36df5d', ''),
(76572, 22959, 34813, 'Ribbon', 'Gold Lamé (17)', 0.0000, '+', 1, 0, '+', 1, 1, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, '', '', 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 3, 29, '30:499bc45895cd0baaef055a57cb36df5d', ''),
(76573, 22959, 34813, 'Initials (Max 4)', 'LJD', 3.3000, '+', 1, 0, '+', 1, 1, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, '', '', 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 2, 0, '30:499bc45895cd0baaef055a57cb36df5d', ''),
(76574, 22959, 34813, 'Plastic pockets', '1 at back (free)', 0.0000, '+', 1, 0, '+', 1, 1, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, '', '', 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 0, 6, 84, '30:499bc45895cd0baaef055a57cb36df5d', ''),
```

I need to be able to take all the results stored in the products_options_values field (note, there are six just for this order) and store them as a comma separated list in the tradebox_attributes_list field.

EDITED AS REQUIREMENTS JUST BEEN CHANGED:

I'm about to throw a spanner in the works now. group_concat() will work, but i have just been asked to display one of the attributes on a separate line. For instance, we want the following:
  6 Period Day, Navy, 1 at back (free) *NEW LINE*
  LJD  £3.30

Not so simple now as i need to select specific products_options_values, then on a separate line, select a different option and it's associated price from the options_values_price field.

Comment: There is smell of bad design - why would you join records into a string and store them in another place of the db? Normalize your schema and use `JOIN`s.

Comment: @StevePrice is this the output of your above query? `6 period day (TP6)NavyGold (j)Gold Lamé (17)LJD1 at back (free)` isn't supposed to come in few rows? Then you could use `group_concat`. Or you are saying you want to split it by `,`?

Comment: @bonCodigo Yes, need a string separated by ,

Comment: @moonwave99 It probably is bad design, but we are looking for a quick solution to a problem without a total rewrite. The program was never designed to take attributes into account, and if we just add the attributes field to the existing db query it will list the main product 6 times as it loops through each of the attributes, multiply the cost by 6 in the process. We just need to get all the attribute names into one string that is then passed to the code that creates a .csv file

Comment: Really creepy design... sorry to say that. So we have to believe that string is just one row/value in a column? To be frank, if you are pulling e.g. 10 rows for same order id. You can use `group_concat` to put those 10 rows into one row seperated by `,`. ... :$

Comment: @bonCodigo I can post the entire current php code if you want to see how it works. Maybe you can see a better solution to insert the attributes as one string as opposed to the loop it is currently running through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use a `group_concat()` to get the values group by `order id`. Wish we could see the table though..

```
SELECT group_concat(products_options_values)
FROM orders_products_attributes oa
WHERE oa.orders_id
IN (
SELECT DISTINCT o.orders_id
FROM orders o
WHERE o.exported =  '0'
AND o.orders_id >  '0')
group by oa.orders_id;
```